# Querying the Team names with more than a half wins (Database contains Home and Away Column for results)

Tags: sql

I have a table (Meetings) which contains the following columns:

- HomeTeam(varchar)
- AwayTeam(varchar)
- Home(int)
- Away(int)

For the scores (Example: 3:2).

My problem is that I need to output all teams which have more than a half wins.

The code provided is working perfect, but it is only for the Home Wins and I need a sum of both Home and Away, because for example, 'Liverpool' has three Home games and two Away games and I need from both sides scores.

```sql
SELECT Team, COUNT(*) AS HomeWins
FROM Teams
JOIN Meetings ON Team = Meetings.HomeTeam AND Meetings.Home > Meetings.Away
GROUP BY Team
```

The expected output is (from 6 teams I have two teams which have 3 wins and the other one - 4) to output the teams with more than a half wins and their wins total.

Example:

```
Team       Wins
Liverpool  4
PSG        3
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... Also you need to tag a RDMS product, the sql tag on this website does not mean a RDMS product but the ANSI/ISO SQL standard..

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want wins, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from meetings m
        where (m.hometeam = t.team and m.home > m.away) or
              (m.awayteam = t.team and m.away > m.away)
       ) as num_wins
from team t;
```

Note:  This returns all teams, even those who have not won any games.

Comment: Thanks man, this works perfectly, but I need to filter the teams which from 5 games have less than 3 won games.

For example:
Barcelona 1W, Bayern 3W, Juventus 1W, Liverpool 4W, ManUnited 2W, PSG 3W.
I want to get only Bayern, Liverpool and PSG.

Comment: @S1C4R10 . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, which is more specific on your actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query the results twice, inverting the query and using UNION to create a combined view.

```
create table #meetings (HomeTeam varchar(20), AwayTeam varchar(20), Home int, Away int);


insert into #meetings (HomeTeam, AwayTeam, Home, Away)
values
    ('Trumpton', 'Camberwick Green', 1, 0), -- Trumpton win
    ('Chigley', 'Camberwick Green', 3, 2), -- Chigley win
    ('Trumpton', 'Chigley', 3, 1), -- Trumpton win
    ('Camberwick Green', 'Trumpton', 0, 2), -- Trumpton win
    ('Camberwick Green', 'Chigley', 1, 2) -- Chigley win

/*
Trumpton - played 3, won 3
Camberwick Green - played 4, won 0
Chigley - played 3, won 2
*/

select
    Team
    ,count(*) as Played
    ,sum(Win) as Wins
from
    (
    select
        HomeTeam as Team
        ,case when Home > Away then 1 else 0 end as Win
    from
        #meetings
    union all
    select
        AwayTeam as Team
        ,case when Away > Home then 1 else 0 end as Win
    from
        #meetings
    ) results
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to return info for teams that have more wins than losses.  If that's correct here is one way to do it:

```sql
-- Build cte to re-use query
WITH meetings(WinningTeam, LosingTeam) AS (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN Home > Away THEN HomeTeam ELSE AwayTeam END AS WinningTeam,
    CASE WHEN Home > Away THEN AwayTeam ELSE HomeTeam END AS LosingTeam
  FROM Meetings
)
SELECT teams.Team, wins.win_count AS Wins
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT WinningTeam, COUNT(*) AS win_count
  FROM Meetings
  GROUP BY 1
) wins ON teams.team = wins.WinningTeam -- Get wins per team
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT LosingTeam, count(*) AS loss_count
  FROM Meetings
  GROUP BY 1
) losses ON teams.team = wins.LosingTeam -- Get wins per team
WHERE win_count > loss_count -- Only return teams with winning records
```